# How to remove a task from ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: java, android, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a `ScheduledExecutorService` that times a few different task periodically with `scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable, INIT_DELAY, ACTION_DELAY, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

I also have a different `Runnable` that I'm using with this scheduler.
the problem starts when I want to remove one of the tasks from the scheduler.

Is there a way to do this?

Am I doing the right thing using one scheduler for different tasks?
What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Simply cancel the future returned by `scheduledAtFixedRate()`:

```
// Create the scheduler
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
// Create the task to execute
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
};
// Schedule the task such that it will be executed every second
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture =
    scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(r, 1L, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// Wait 5 seconds
Thread.sleep(5000L);
// Cancel the task
scheduledFuture.cancel(false);
```

Another thing to note is that cancel does not remove the task from scheduler. All it ensures is that `isDone` method always return `true`. This may lead to memory leaks if you keep adding such tasks. For e.g.: if you start a task based on some client activity or UI button click, repeat it n-times and exit. If that button is clicked too many times, you might end up with big pool of threads that cannot be garbage collected as scheduler still has a reference.

You may want to use `setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true)` in `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` class available in Java 7 onwards. For backward compatibility, default is set to false.

Comment: Note to people using `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` as it doesn't expose the inner executor: Create an executor yourself, set the property, then wrap it with `Executors.unconfigurableScheduledExecutorService()`.

Comment: Why I can't reuse it? Why so hard to get cancelled tasks removed?

Comment: To use `setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true)`, see the explanation of the instantiation variants for `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36748183/3072570.

Answer (score 1):

If your `ScheduledExecutorService` instance extends `ThreadPoolExecutor` (e.g. `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`), you could use `remove(Runnable)` (but see the note in its javadoc: "It may fail to remove tasks that have been converted into other forms before being placed on the internal queue.") or `purge()`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, at the time this method didn't exist in `Executor`