# How to setRemoveOnCancelPolicy for Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have this:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledThreadPool = Executors
        .newScheduledThreadPool(5);
```

Then I start a task like so:

```
scheduledThreadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, seconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I preserve the reference to the Future this way:

```
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = scheduledThreadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, seconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I want to be able to cancel **and remove** the future

```
scheduledFuture.cancel(true);
```

However this SO answer notes that canceling doesn't remove it and adding new tasks will end in many tasks that can't be GCed.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14423578/2576903

They mention something about `setRemoveOnCancelPolicy`, however this `scheduledThreadPool` doesn't have such method. What do I do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(boolean)) is declared in [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html).

```
/**
 * Sets the policy on whether cancelled tasks should be immediately
 * removed from the work queue at time of cancellation.  This value is
 * by default {@code false}.
 *
 * @param value if {@code true}, remove on cancellation, else don't
 * @see #getRemoveOnCancelPolicy
 * @since 1.7
 */
public void setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(boolean value) {
    removeOnCancel = value;
}
```

This executor is returned by Executors class by [newScheduledThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool(int)) and similar methods.

```
public static ScheduledExecutorService newScheduledThreadPool(int corePoolSize) {
    return new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize);
}
```

So in short, you can cast the executor service reference to call the method

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor ex = (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
ex.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);
```

or create `new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` by yourself.

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor ex = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);
ex.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);
```

Comment: What do you mean cast the executor service reference? Also how do I create a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor by myself, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Damn. I am developing an Android Application and this call `setRemoveOnCancelPolicy` requires API level 21 and my project supports API way back to 14. Is there another way to remove tasks?

Comment: Is there any chance that cancel(false) will raise execipion? The java doc does not declare any exceptions.

Comment: @Jaskey canceling future should raise CancellationException on a caller thread that executes #get method, it should not throw exception in invoker thread