# shutdown only one task in ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java

I have a few tasks which are registered by

```
final ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
List<ScheduledFuture<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        tasks.forEach(task->{
            var future = ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> run(task), 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            futures.add(future);
});

// and now cancel all tasks one for one after 10 seconds..
ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() ->
        {
            log.info("cancel task----");
            futures.get(0).cancel(false);
        }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

As you can see, for each task the `futures` holds a `task.getId()` so I can obtain the `ScheduledFuture` of a task afterwards. I do not want to `ses.shutdown()` because this will shutdown the whole schedulings for the other tasks as well, which I want to avoid.

The only solution I actually see is to create one `ScheduledExecutorService` for each task to be able to shutdown it afterwards for a specified task, but then I cannot make use of the pooling.

**How can I shutdown only a specified task within the pool?**

Comment: `scheduleWithFixedDelay` has a return value which provides you with an API which does what you want.

Comment: I see only `getScheduledFuture().cancel(false)` but this will only cancel the task of the **actual** schedule and not the next. So the next schedule will have the task again, I dont want to cancel it over and over again..I want to remove this task completly from the queue. I dont see an appropriate API for that.

Comment: cancel will cancel the task and any further scheduling of it, the boolean parameter decides if you want to throw an interruption exception on the task if it is already running and blocking on a resource.

Comment: @nimo23, while it's true that by default cancelled tasks won't be removed from the executor's queue immediately, the executor won't run the cancelled task any more - because `FutureTask` is a stateful object, and it won't run the actual task code in `CANCELLED` state.

Comment: @prokhorov This is wrong. As long as the task is within the scheduled executor's queue the next task will run..does not matter if you cancel it in the actual run..for the actual run it is cancelled but not for the next run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
Future<?> future;
future.cancel(false);
```

Cancel will cancel the task and any further scheduling of it.¹ The Boolean parameter decides if you want to throw an interruption exception on the task if it is already running and blocking on a resource.

To ensure the task is removed from the queue immediately upon cancelling, use the setRemoveOnCancelPolicy method on your ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor and set the policy to true.²

```
final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor ses = (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
ses.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);
```

¹ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Future.html

² https://stackoverflow.com/a/36748183/4425643 , https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#setRemoveOnCancelPolicy-boolean-

Comment: I am seeing a removeOnCancel boolean field of ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor and I'm trying to determine how that's configured. Perhaps in your case it's set to false?

Comment: I updated my code..and according my example the cancel of one task in the actual schedule does not cancel the same task in the next schedule. So further scheduling is not cancelled..

Comment: I need to continue my research until I figure out how to set the setRemoveOnCancelPolicy

Comment: That is interesting. Cannot see how to set `removeOnCancel` to true. It is very likely that `new Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);` sets this property to `false`. But I cannot see how to set this to `true`.

Comment: Edited the answer