# Cancelling Scheduler Executor when response is Success

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled executor service. It Will call a rest api every 30 seconds. The response is either WAITING or SUCCESS. i need to cancel the executor once the response is SUCCESS.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
ScheduledFuture<?> task = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(
    () -> //Calling a RestApi returing a response of SUCCESS or WAITING
, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Have you checked the Javadoc of ScheduledFuture? I immediately see a method (in super-interface Future) `cancel` and if you read it's Javadoc, you see that it does what you want: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-

Comment: but where will I call that?

Comment: You call it from the code that checks whether the response equals "SUCCESS".

Comment: but the future is the task. how can I call it inside?

Answer (score 1):

The general answer to your question can be found on [How to remove a task from ScheduledExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423449/how-to-remove-a-task-from-scheduledexecutorservice)

However to answer your specific question, "how can I do it from within the task?" - it's slightly trickier. You want to avoid the (unlikely) race condition where your task completes before the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method completes and makes the reference to the `ScheduledFuture` available to be stored in a field.

The below code solves this by using a `CompletableFuture` to store the reference to the `ScheduledFuture` that represents the task.

```
public class CancelScheduled {
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;
    private CompletableFuture<ScheduledFuture<?>> taskFuture;

    public CancelScheduled() {
        scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
        ((ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) scheduledExecutorService).setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);
    }

    public void run() {
        taskFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        ScheduledFuture<?> task = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                () -> {
                    // Get the result of the REST call (stubbed with "SUCCESS" below)
                    String result = "SUCCESS";
                    if (result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                        // Get the reference to my own `ScheduledFuture` in a race-condition free way
                        ScheduledFuture<?> me;
                        try {
                            me = taskFuture.get();
                        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                        me.cancel(false);
                    }
                }, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // Supply the reference to the `ScheduledFuture` object to the task itself in a race-condition free way
        taskFuture.complete(task);
    }
```